# How to find number duplicate values by associated id per value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a messaging system with database tables like below. UID is the users id, and sid is the store id that is sending the message.

```
UID   SID   Content
1     10    "blah" 
1     11     ...
2     10     ...
3     12     ...
3     12     ...
3     10     ...
```

I want to group users with the number of messages they have received per store. So the output will be

```
UID   NumUniqueSIDs
1     1     (corresponds to uid = 1, sid = 10)
1     1     (corresponds to uid = 1, sid = 11)
2     1     (corresponds to UID = 2, sid = 10)
3     2     (corresponds to UID = 3, sid = 12)
3     1     (corresponds to UID = 3, sid = 10)
```

I have been unable to come up with a query that accomplishes this. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY UID, SID`.

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like a fairly typical `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` query

Comment: `SELECT uid, count(sid) FROM Messages GROUP BY uid, sid;`

Comment: The above query solved this issue for me. Thanks @GordonLinoff for the hint. I feel dumb for asking a question with such a simple answer, but thank you for your help. I had everything except grouping on two columns.

Answer (score 1):

The following query produces the correct results:

```
SELECT uid, count(sid) as NumUniqueSIDs from Messages group by uid, sid
```